# DB for Analyzing user mobile app activity - Mongo or Redis or something else?

Tags: android, mongodb, redis, data-modeling

We have Terabytes of data every month coming in from our mobile app. The data is event data which indicates user action within the app.
Right now, the data is simply like a log of all users activity living in Mongo.
Ex:

```
{_id: "User1", "action": "Click_WatchNews", "details":{....}}
{_id: "User2", "action": "Click_Ad", "details":{....}}
{_id: "User3", "action": "Tweet_Article_72h3j9104", "details":{....}}
....
{_id: "User1", "action": "Click_PurchaseSubscription", "details":{....}}
....
```

In the above example we'd like to understand "What motivated 'User1' to Purchase?" i.e. In order to understand user behaviour, we would have to aggregate datapoints related for every user and this would be time and space consuming (in Mongo atleast). 
The question is,

Do we reduce time and computation complexity by switching our DB to Redis or something else?

Comment: It would help to know the latency you can tolerate.  A couple questions: Does the data stream in or arrive in batches, and if batches what is the frequency?  How current does the data have to be when you ask the questions?  Within a month, a day, or near real time?  Are you expecting this to respond to ad-hoc interactive queries?

Answer (score 0):

Migrating to Redis will help with time by throwing resources at it. I don't think it will do much for complexity. Perhaps do filtering for users you won't do analytics on.